# Running an Applescript after build phase in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, applescript

I have an Applescript that opens the Safari developer tools. This saves me from the hassle of clicking Develop -> Inspect -> index.html every time I build a Cordova / Phonegap app.

I would now like to invoke this Applescript when I build the project and open it in the simulator.

I've tried adding a building phase and adding the script as instructed in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaRunScriptBuildPhase.html.

However when I build the project in XCode I'm getting an error: `"auto_opendevtools.applescript: bad interpreter: Permission denied"`. Seems all the permissions are fine.

How I entered the script in the build phase:

[image]

Leads to error:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "**Add Run Script Build Phase**" need a shell command or a path of the shell script.

To run an **AppleScript** from a shell script, you must use the `osascript` command.

```
osascript "/the path of/auto_opendevtools.applescript"
```

Comment: So should you put `osascript "/the path of/auto_opendevtools.applescript` Where it says "Shell:" or paste it in the field with that line of code above it?

Comment: @John Types the path or paste it in the field above the Shell's field

Comment: Or put `#!/usr/bin/env osascript` at the top of your script